# Distributed Erlang: Learn about remote host and start function

Tags: erlang, distributed-computing

I am trying to implement a really simple example to get a first look into **Distributed Erlang**. So, I start two nodes on the same machine:

```
erl -sname dilbert
erl -sname dogbert
```

The task is that `dogbert` makes `dilbert` output `Hello, World!` using a simple `fun () -> io:format("Hello, World!") end` on node `dilbert`. I thought this would be easy with `dogbert`'s shell:

```
(dogbert@centraldogma.fubar)1> spawn(dilbert, fun () -> io:format("HELLO!") end).
<0.39.0>

=ERROR REPORT==== 13-Jun-2012::17:49:04 ===
** Can not start erlang:apply,[#Fun<erl_eval.20.82930912>,[]] on dilbert **
```

In the same shell, using `nodes().` outputs `[]`. Well, `dogbert` obviously doesn't know about `dilbert`, but why is that the case? Or, how do I make nodes in distributed erlang get to know each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. You must set a common cookie for both nodes so they can interact.

   erl -sname dilbert -setcookie pointyhairedboss
   erl -sname dogbert -setcookie pointyhairedboss
2. You must specify the hostname of the node you want to connect to.
   spawn('dogbert@yourhostname', fun () -> io:format("HELLO!") end).

Comment: Since he started them on the same machine (and presumably from the same user account), they should automatically get the same default cookie.